# Trying to override react-bootstrap css in a NextJS project

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a Next.js project and trying to use Bootstrap as the CSS framework. I have installed `react-bootstrap` to the project and then started building the navigation bar. I'm trying to add an '.active' class to one of the navigation bar links to show it is the currently active one but I'm having trouble overriding Bootstrap's properties in my own CSS.

I am importing the bootstrap css into the `_app.tsx` file like so:

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import Header from './layouts/Header';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );

}
export default MyApp
```

I have my navigation inside a component called Header.js:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link';

import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styles from '../../styles/Header.module.css';

import headerLogo from '../../public/img/header-logo.png';

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Head>
                <title>Test Project</title>
                <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
            </Head>
            <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="light" style={{ maxWidth: '1440px' }} >
                <Navbar.Brand href='/'>
                    <Image src={headerLogo} alt="logo" />
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-nabar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="me-auto">
                        <Link href="/"><Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link></Link>
                        <Link href="/page1"><Nav.Link className={styles.active}>Active Page</Nav.Link></Link>
                        <Link href="/page2"><Nav.Link>Page 2</Nav.Link></Link>
                        <Link href="/page3"><Nav.Link>Page 3</Nav.Link></Link>
                        <Link href="/about"><Nav.Link>About Us</Nav.Link></Link>
                        <Link href="/contact"><Nav.Link>Contact Us</Nav.Link></Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Header;
```

and here is my simple css:

`.active { color: red;     }`

I'm importing the Bootstrap components I need from `react-bootstrap` and building my nav bar. That works fine but as you can see, I'm trying to add a class called '.active' from my CSS Module `Header.module.css` to the "Active Page" `Nav.Link`. When I try and do this, the CSS is applied but if I look in DevTools it is being overriden by Bootstrap's `.nav-link` `color: rgba(0,0,0,.55)` property.

No matter what order the import statements are, it always seems to be the case that the Bootstrap CSS properties end up overriding anything I've written into `Header.module.css`. Am I importing `react-bootstrap` incorrectly? Is there something that has to be done differently this is a Next.js project, not a standard React project?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you

P.S. Here is how it looks in DevTools in case it helps:

[image: DevTools]

Comment: I'm a little late to the party but i have the same issue described here. did you solve the issue in the end? did you end up adding important to every css rule?

Answer (score 0):

try adding !important after so -> color: #0d6efd !important;

Comment: !important works of course but it's a really bad way of going about it, having to add "!important" to everything messes with specificity and just makes everything harder. There must be a better way to just override Bootstrap as you would in another non-Next.js project, right?

Comment: if your scoping within the page under <Styles> it will not affect the other instances for this bootstrap class unless youre using it multiple times on the scoped page. . . then yes adding another class name would be more appropriate

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I am creating a CSS module for the component as I've shown in Header.js but no matter what css rules I set up in it, if any of the properties conflict with bootstrap, bootstrap **always** takes precedence. That is the example I have shown with '.active'. I'm not sure what you mean by using <Styles>?

Comment: i'm thinking of vue.js... for react styles you can add a className in the <link> and use the color there just add that class to the styles sheet

Comment: That's the issue, the CSS that is added in the CSS Module stylesheet is **always** overriden by Bootstrap's CSS for the same properties. Did you read the question at all?

Comment: yes that is where adding !important to your class you made can help

Comment: Okay but then imagine I want another class that changes the text color for another reason, this will always be overridden by the property with "!important" added to it. It's just not a good solution and breaks the point of CSS i.e. cascading and specificity. Sorry but it is not a good solution.

Comment: not familiar with inline styling for React can you do style="color: red" ?? like we would in html?

Comment: Yes but then every single html element would need inline styling like that and it would make the code really hard to read, refactor, scale etc. It's just not a good solution. Thanks for trying to help but I'm just going to move on now, the library seems to just be broken for nextjs if you want to do anything more than alter scss variables.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that bootstrap offers a more detailed selector. So you could create a more detailed selector as well, providing classNames for a few upper elements. And you can use `!import` of course, as it was mentioned above.

**Update:**
On your screenshot you see that there is a `.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link` rule, so you have to create a similar one and add your own selector as well. Here you will need to switch to global scope like it's explained here: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#exceptions

So the rule in `Header.module.css` might look like:

```css
:global(.navbar-light) :global(.navbar-nav) :global(.nav-link).active {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean with the first part. I am providing a more specific selector. All of the "normal" nav links have the class "nav-link" and the the one that is active has "nav-link" and "active", however the "color" property of nav-link **always** overrides the "color" property of "active". Do you understand what I'm mean? Maybe I explained it poorly.

The issue is there is no way to override bootstrap, it seems like it's CSS files are imported after the Module's CSS file by Next.js or something like that. That is why I'm asking how to properly use bootstrap with Next.js

Comment: Here you can find some explanations about what I have meant: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/css/precedence.html

Comment: Thank you for the link but that is exactly the problem. Using `!important` is an awful solution because it breaks cascading and specificity inside my own CSS file. The specificity is not the issue either, they are both class declarations. The issue is the sequence of declaration. For some unknown next.js reason, it is importing the bootstrap css files **after** the module files and there seems to be no way around this. If I'm using Bootstrap on a non-next.js project, it's very easy to just import my CSS file last, meaning that my CSS overrides the bootstrap CSS. This is the entire problem...

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: in this case the order of importing css styles doesn't matter, because the bootstraps selector consist of three css class names, but you selector is of one class name (thus, it's less detailed)

Comment: That's not how it works, I have overidden Bootstrap in dozens of other projects, this is the first time I've tried to in Next.js. The fact that there are 3 selectors before it finds the correct selector to apply the rules to doesn't matter.

Comment: I've just seen your edit to the answer and thank you for the effort, I tried that and put it in my `globals.css` file but it made no difference, Bootstrap's rules are always overriding mine, no matter what.

Comment: The rule I've provided is for your `Header.module.css`

Comment: I tried it in both but neither worked. I'm just going to give up on bootstrap in a Next.js project, thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following fixed it for me using scss and the NextJS App router:

1. Create app.scss file in /app
2. `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` in /app/app.scss
3. `import './app.scss'` in /app/layout.js

I'm trying to find a reason this happens, no luck yet.